# is there any way to get milliseconds on google stackdriver log?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster and using stackdriver to log all container events; however the logs all show ".000" in millisecond, is there any way to enable millisecond logging?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. [It's a limitation of the underlying Fluentd agent](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/21480#issuecomment-190341643) that collects all the logs off of the nodes, which has only recently been fixed in their latest release. It should be pulled into the next release of Kubernetes, but isn't there yet.

Comment: Thanks Alex. By next release, do you mean Kubernetes 1.3?

Comment: I mean Kubernetes 1.4, unfortunately.

Comment: how about now, we are on 1.9.7-gke.11  but still no ms

Comment: Sorry @dancarter, I'm pretty far removed from this stuff now. You'll have best results either drawing someone else's attention to this question or asking in the Kubernetes Slack community at http://slack.k8s.io/